# jQuery animated hover menu bar improvements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I've made a fiddle which can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MCPke/1/

It's a navigation bar with an active state and when you hover over another link in the nav bar, the active state image animates to that position.

I think it's quite clumsy though so I was hoping someone could help with some improvements?

What I'd like to do is use padding between the links so that instead of snapping back when hovering over the white space between links, it will actually stay active on the nav item immediately to the left of that white space.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Normally I would post the code in the question too but the jQuery for this is quite long but if asked for I will update the question with it.

Comment: You are setting the margin on the `li` item, which stops the `a` item "filling" the `li`. To rectify, remove any margin/padding from your `li` and apply them to your A

Comment: thanks, been messing around with it and think I've just about got it.